# ffmpeg black screen issue for video video generation from a list of frames

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I used a video to generate a list of frames from it, then I wanted to create multiple videos from this list of frames.
I've set starting and ending frames indexes for each "sub video", so for example,
`indexes = [[0, 64], [64, 110], [110, 234], [234, 449]]`, and those indexes will help my code generate 4 videos of various durations. The idea is to decompose the original video into multiple sub videos. My code is working just fine, the video generated.

But every sub video start with multiple seconds of black screen, only the first generated video (so the one using `indexes[0]` for starting and ending frames) is generated without this black screen part. I've tried changing the frame rate for each `sub_video`, according to the number of frames and things like that, but I didn't work. You can find my code below

```py
for i, (start_idx, end_idx) in enumerate(self.video_frames_indexes):
    if end_idx - start_idx > 10:
        shape = cv2.imread(f'output/video_reconstitution/{video_name}/final/frame_{start_idx}.jpg').shape
        os.system(f'ffmpeg -r 30 -s {shape[0]}x{shape[1]} -i output/video_reconstitution/{video_name}/final/frame_%d.JPG'
              f' -vf "select=between(n\,{start_idx}\,{end_idx})" -vcodec libx264 -crf 25'
              f' output/video_reconstitution/IMG_7303/sub_videos/serrage_{i}.mp4')
```

Just the ffmpeg command

```bash
ffmpeg -r 30 -s {shape[0]}x{shape[1]} -i output/video_reconstitution/{video_name}/final/frame_%d.JPG -vf "select=between(n\,{start_idx}\,{end_idx})" -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 output/video_reconstitution/IMG_7303/sub_videos/serrage_{i}.mp4
```

Comment: Why are you using `-s {shape[0]}x{shape[1]}` with JPEG images? The JPEG image resolution is stored in the image. In case you really mean to use `-s`, it should be `-s {shape[1]}x{shape[0]}`. Does all the JPEG images have the same resolution? Can you make a reproducible example using synthetic image, say: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=500 frame_%d.jpg`? Please try to avoid question with long nested confusing paths like `output/video_reconstitution/{video_name}/final` and `output/video_reconstitution/IMG_7303/sub_videos/`. Avoid using `self.video_frames_indexes`

Comment: @Rotem The video is resized prior to generating the frames, that's why I used -s because every time I use a new main video to generate sub ones, the frames shape changes, but I didn't know that you had to invert shape[0] and shape[1]. Sorry for confusing you with the path

Comment: From your comment, I don't understand if all the JPEG images in the same folder have the same "shape" or not. Please let me know if the answer I posted solves the "black screen" issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues that might cause black screen issue at the start.

Few video players shows black video when the timestamps are not starting from zero.
`select` filter doesn't reset the timestamps to start form zero, and just pass them through.
That means that files that doesn't start from the first frame starts with timestamps that are not zero.
For testing, we may use FFprobe (from command line):

`ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -show_entries packet=pts_time -of compact=p=0 serrage_2.mp4`

---

For removing the offset, we may use [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) after `select` filter:
`-vf "select=between(n\,{start_idx}\,{end_idx}),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS"`

The expression `PTS-STARTPTS` subtracts the first PTS (timestamp) from all the timestamps (`-` is a minus sign not a dash).

---

We don't suppose to use `-s {shape[0]}x{shape[1]}` for JPEG images, because the input size of the image is know.
In case we really want to, we have to swap the indices: `-s {shape[1]}x{shape[0]}`.
`shape[1]` is the width, and `shape[0]` is the height...

---

For testing we may use FFmpeg for creating 500 JPEG images:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=500 frame_%d.jpg`

(Note that the first index is `1`).

---

Updated code sample:

```
import os
import cv2

indexes = [[1, 64], [64, 110], [110, 234], [234, 449]]

for i, (start_idx, end_idx) in enumerate(indexes):
    if end_idx - start_idx > 10:
        shape = cv2.imread(f'/Tmp/jpeg_frames/frame_{start_idx}.jpg').shape
        os.system(f'ffmpeg -y -r 30 -s {shape[1]}x{shape[0]} -i /Tmp/jpeg_frames/frame_%d.JPG'
              f' -vf "select=between(n\,{start_idx}\,{end_idx}),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS" -vcodec libx264 -crf 25'
              f' /Tmp/jpeg_frames/serrage_{i}.mp4')
```

---

In case the JPEG images have different resolutions, it may also be a reason for depredated MP4 files.
In case of different resolutions, it is recommended to resize the images using OpenCV for example (not using FFmpeg).

Comment: Great explanations ! The timestamp was the issue, adding setpts=PTS-STARTPTS fixed my problem, thank you very much